# sbt testOnly exclusion list with tag does not work

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest

I have a test class as

```scala
import org.scalatest.FlatSpec

import scala.collection.mutable

class Tags101Spec extends FlatSpec {
  "A Stack" should "pop values in last-in-first-out order" in {
    val stack = new mutable.Stack[Int]
    stack.push(1)
    stack.push(2)
    assert(stack.pop() === 2)
    assert(stack.pop() === 1)
  }

  it should "throw NoSuchElementException if an empty stack is popped" in {
    val emptyStack = new mutable.Stack[String]
    intercept[NoSuchElementException] {
      emptyStack.pop()
    }
  }

  "A String" should "return 0 size when empty" taggedAs (Fast) in {
    assert("".size === 0)
  }

  "A Sorted List of 10 numbers" must "return 10 as the first element when reversed" taggedAs (Slow) in {
    assert(10 === (1 to 10).toList.reverse.head)
  }

}
```

In the same directory, I have a class called `Tags` which looks like

```scala
import org.scalatest.Tag

object Slow extends Tag("Slow Tests")
object Fast extends Tag("Fast Tests")
```

I run my tests using `sbt` by including a tag using `-n` flag and it works

```scala
sbt:Unit Testing in Scala> testOnly -- -n Fast
[info] Tags101Spec:
[info] A Stack
[info] A String
[info] A Sorted List of 10 numbers
[info] Run completed in 137 milliseconds.
[info] Total number of tests run: 0
[info] Suites: completed 1, aborted 0
[info] Tests: succeeded 0, failed 0, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
```

Since only `1` test was `taggedAs(Fast)`, the test ran only one test.

Now, I want to do the opposite, exclude the `Fast` tag and run remaining tests. Here is what I tried

```scala
sbt:Unit Testing in Scala> testOnly -- -l Fast
[info] Tags101Spec:
[info] A Stack
[info] - should pop values in last-in-first-out order
[info] - should throw NoSuchElementException if an empty stack is popped
[info] A String
[info] - should return 0 size when empty
[info] A Sorted List of 10 numbers
[info] - must return 10 as the first element when reversed
[info] Run completed in 252 milliseconds.
[info] Total number of tests run: 4
[info] Suites: completed 1, aborted 0
[info] Tests: succeeded 4, failed 0, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
```

And as you see, it ran `4` tests, which is all the tests, including `1` `Fast` tagged test.

What am I missing here? How can I make exclusion tag work with `sbt`?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The argument to `-l` or `-n` should be the `name` string argument passed to `Tag`s constructor, not the name of the object. For example, given

```
object Slow extends Tag("SlowTests")
object Fast extends Tag("FastTests")
```

then exclude with

```
testOnly -- -l FastTests
```

instead of

```
testOnly -- -l Fast
```

which outputs

```
[info] Tags101Spec:
[info] A Stack
[info] - should pop values in last-in-first-out order
[info] - should throw NoSuchElementException if an empty stack is popped
[info] A String
[info] A Sorted List of 10 numbers
[info] - must return 10 as the first element when reversed
[info] Run completed in 187 milliseconds.
[info] Total number of tests run: 3
[info] Suites: completed 1, aborted 0
[info] Tests: succeeded 3, failed 0, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
[info] All tests passed.
```

where we see `A string` test did not execute.

Personally I would use a fully qualified name as the `name` argument when constructing `Tag`s like so

```
package example

import org.scalatest.Tag

object Slow extends Tag("example.Slow")
object Fast extends Tag("example.Fast")
```

and execute with

```
testOnly -- -n example.Fast
```

which outputs

```
[info] Tags101Spec:
[info] A Stack
[info] A String
[info] - should return 0 size when empty
[info] A Sorted List of 10 numbers
[info] Run completed in 158 milliseconds.
[info] Total number of tests run: 1
[info] Suites: completed 1, aborted 0
[info] Tests: succeeded 1, failed 0, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
[info] All tests passed.
```

Comment: Thanks @Mario. What's the benefit we get with qualified name like `"example.Slow"`?